# How to update/mount/create ISO image as read write

Tags: linux, images, iso-image

Is there a way to do the following in Linux:

1. Mount the ISO image as read/write
2. Create the ISO image as RW
3. Update the ISO image.

I am creating the image using the following command and the image "test.iso" mounts are read only preventing me to update the ISO files.
"mkisofs -input-charset iso8859-1 -J -r -hide-rr-moved -joliet-long -o test.iso Test/"

Comment: I think this belongs to [su]

Comment: See also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26237/iso-file-readonly

Answer (score 4):

1. No. The ISO9660 driver doesn't have any write support.
2. Meaningless. Either the filesystem driver has write support, or it does not. You can use a filesystem that *does* have write support such as ext2, but then you won't have a ISO image (although wodim and the like won't care, and will burn it regardless).
3. Use software such as ISO Master to do so.

Comment: Basically i need a read/write hybrid image which can show up as CDROM in Windows & MAC. Other file systems such as EXT2/FAT doesn't really work as CDROM especially in MAC and it really doesn't matter what format i am using as long as MAC is happy.

Comment: `isomaster` still working in `2024` to edit a hybrid `iso` image